# GB2ShapeCache accessing issue

Tags: box2d

I am using cocos2dx 2.2.6 and box2d in my android project. I am trying to add shapes from plist but GB2ShapeCache is not accessible. It is showing as GB2ShapeCache_x_h, which is the definition in the GB2ShapeCache class. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the entire project. Made a new one. Voila!! It worked.